# How to get an element from a list, set it as an image and show it as a gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help to get all the **traits** from a **list** from another **class** then set them a specific **image** and **show** them simultaneously to the player.

To do so, I created in my UI a **traitSlotContainer** with a grid layout and a **traitSlotTemplate** GameObject with an Image. I would like this **traitSlotTemplate** to be used for each Trait.

I've got a **class** called "**Npc**", which represents one instance of auto generated instanciate NPCs containing their name, stats, traits, skills etc...

Class is in shorter something like that:

```
[Serializable]
public class Npc
{
    public string NameLocalizationKey;
    public int Height;
    public int Weight;
    public string EyeColor;
    public string HairColor;
    public string Haircut;
    public List<Trait> Traits;
}
```

I would like to show the traits proper to the selected NPC.
Note that the instantiate NPC is "**Selected.Npc**"

I reckon that I need first to load the selected NPC trait list, get one trait, instantiate it as GameObject then change it's sprite to the adequate one. And redo.

How am I suppose to do that?

my trait class is as below:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Trait
    {
        public string NameLocalizationKey;
        public string DescriptionLocalizationKey;
        public string[] IncompatibleTraitLocalizationKey;
        public StatName Stat1AffectedName;
        public int Stat1AffectedValue;
        public TraitStatEffectUnit Stat1AffectedUnit;
        public StatName Stat2AffectedName;
        public int Stat2AffectedValue;
        public TraitStatEffectUnit Stat2AffectedUnit;
        public TraitCondition Condition;
        public bool StartingTrait;
        public bool IsNegative;
        public bool AffectStat;
}
```

**NameLocalizationKey** is always like that: trait_name_trait1, trait_name_trait2 etc.. and value are stored into a GameData.json

And my traitAsset class is like that:

```
public class TraitAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TraitAssets Instance { get; private set; }
    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    public Sprite spendthriftySprite;
    public Sprite thriftySprite;
    public Sprite studiousSprite;
    public Sprite lazySprite;
}
```

I found an online tutorial and did that:

```
public Sprite GetTraitSprite(string NameLocalizationKey)
        {
            switch (NameLocalizationKey)
            {
                default:
                case "trait_name_lazy": return TraitAssets.Instance.lazySprite;
                case "trait_name_spendthrifty": return TraitAssets.Instance.spendthriftySprite;
                case "trait_name_studious": return TraitAssets.Instance.studiousSprite;
                case "trait_name_thrifty": return TraitAssets.Instance.thriftySprite;
            }
        }
```

I am really new to Unity and I try to figure out what my dev (who abandoned me due to lack of motivation but did an incredible job so far) have done.

Sorry for my unclear formulation and thanks for your answer.
Instead of a "all done result" or answer, if one could explain me step by step how to achieve what I asked that would be marvelously kind. If you give a hungry man a fish, you feed him for a day, but if you teach him how to fish, you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=the+power+of+scriptable+objects

Comment: looks good thanks! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what the vision of this implementation is, since there are a few ways to do this vague idea. Seems like that code right there is doing what its supposed to, so i dont see the problem. Call the function to get the sprites and instantiate them.

> I reckon that I need first to load the selected NPC trait list, get one trait, instantiate it as GameObject then change it's sprite to the adequate one. And redo.
> How am I suppose to do that?:(

Given this exact question, i say just make a new function somewhere (im not familiar with your project) and in it have a for loop that goes through the Traits List and calls that GetTraitSprite function to get it. Then use the unity Instantiate function to spawn it in. To spawn it in game (im assuming you display the sprites onto the unity UI canvas), first create a GameObject prefab in the editor that just holds a sprite component. Spawn in that placeholder with the instantiate. Then in the loop at run time, assign that components sprite to the one GetTraitSprite returns after you've spawned in the template prefab. You could also put an if condition to check the sprite is != null or skip it. The unity Instantiate function returns the spawned gameobject, so you can do whatever you like with it then.

Comment: Hmm I understand what you're telling me to do. I just have no idea how to transpose it in code.

Comment: foreach (string trait in Selected.Npc.Traits)
{
     GetTraitSprite(trait)
}